# App is terminated due to memory pressure while taking multiple pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have tried a lot of solutions provided on other questions which were same as mine but nothing could help me much.

Let me tell you what am I doing. I have a collection view. In that I will display some images which will be captured by camera. I am capturing multiple pictures at a time. All the pictures which I have taken, the address of those images will first save into database and then those images will be displayed in collection view.
Now what happens, when I click 40-50 images at a time, the app is crashed and xcode displays a message something like "app is terminating due to memory pressure". Also I am getting too many memory warnings in logs but actually I was neglecting them.

First I am writing code for taking multiple pictures-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    //Get Image URL from Library
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    NSURL *urlPath = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex != 1) {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        [self insertPicToDB:urlPath];
    }else{
        __block  NSURL *url;
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
            UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            // Request to save the image to camera roll
            [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                if (error) {

                } else {
                    url = assetURL;
                    [self insertPicToDB:url];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After while taking each picture, I am saving image url in db and then at the same time trying to reload the collection view as well.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
collectionCell = (CollectionCell *)[_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
collectionCell.imageView = (UIImageView*)[collectionCell viewWithTag:100];
collectionCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    NSString *fileURL = [[recipeImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"FileUrl"];
collectionCell.imagURL = fileURL;
    if ([fileURL hasPrefix:@"assets-library"]) {
        [self getImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL] :indexPath];
    }else{
        fileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/uploads/thumbnail/%@",[[HttpClient sharedInstance]getBaseURLString],[[fileURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"]lastObject]];
        [collectionCell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
    return collectionCell;
}
```

So the condition is, I will keep clicking the pictures and the pictures will be saving in background. 
And the definition of method "getImageFromURL" is-

```
-(void)getImageFromURL:(NSURL*)yourUrl :(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    @autoreleasepool {
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
        if (iref) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                collectionCell = (CollectionCell*)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (collectionCell) {
                    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
                    UIImage *compressedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    collectionCell.imageView.image = compressedImage;
                }else{
                    collectionCell.imageView.image = nil;
                }
                [collectionCell.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
                [collectionCell setNeedsDisplay];
            });
            iref = nil;
        }
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:yourUrl
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];
}
```

I am also trying to compress the images while fetching in collection view. So I don't think that it is crashing because of collection view. What can be the reason? Is it because of I am using ALAssetsLibrary or something else?

I was debugging it in iPhone 4S with iOS version 7.1.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `setImageWithURL` in a background task? Use `https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage`

Comment: @Sreejith But app is not crashing because of setImageWithUrl method because it will be used when I will get image from server. It is crashing while clicking pictures. That will be called from local itself.